# IDEA 2018 always use system encoding for new project

Tags: intellij-idea

I know there are many same question,but still I can't found solution. 
I use IDEA 2018, and it keeps use system default:GBK encoding for new project and new files in new project. how can I set all project encode with utf-8?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`File` | `Other Settings` | **Default Settings** (or `Configure` | **Settings** from the Welcome Screen), then set the encoding:

[image: default]

It will be applied for all the **new** projects.